# C# Unable to Select Specific Fields into DataTable from ListItemCollection

Tags: c#, sharepoint, datatable

Connecting to a SharePoint list I'm pulling back a ListItemCollection, which is being fed into a DataTable, however I only want to select certain fields from the ListItemCollection into the DataTable. Can anyone advise how to do this. New to C#.

```
Web site = cc.Web;
List targetList = site.Lists.GetByTitle("Team");

DataTable dtData = new DataTable();

CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='TeamClass'/><Value Type='Text'>Retail</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>";
ListItemCollection collListItem = targetList.GetItems(query);

cc.Load(collListItem);
cc.ExecuteQuery();

for (int iCntr1 = 0; iCntr1 < collListItem.Count; iCntr1++)
{
    foreach (var field in collListItem[0].FieldValues.Keys)
    {
        dtData.Columns.Add(field);
    }
    foreach (var item in collListItem)
    {
        DataRow dr = dtData.NewRow();
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of SP is this? If I remember correctly, you can specify which fields are included in your CAML query itself. There may be some others that are included by default, but that should be where you start.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any examples of this?

Comment: Can you do this with CAML or is it just SPQuery?

Comment: The node is called ViewFields: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/214811/caml-query-to-fetch-selected-fields-from-list
It looks like you can use this and set ViewFieldsOnly = true according to the last answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by adding the `<ViewFields>` clause to the xml.

```
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = 
"<View>
<Query>
<Where>
<Contains>
<FieldRef Name='Name' /><Value Type='Text'>House</Value> 
</Contains></Where></Query>" +
"<ViewFields>" +
"<FieldRef Name=Ref />" +
"<FieldRef Name=Name />" +
"</ViewFields>
</View>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating through a collection of list items is not a good solution.

If you're interested in the [graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), then you can just return specific fields when getting a collection of list items.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
    new QueryOption("expand", "fields(select=Name,Color,Quantity)")
};

var items = await graphClient.Sites["{site-id}"].Lists["{list-id}"].Items
    .Request( queryOptions )
    .GetAsync();
```